# Ratio of the area of intersection between two circles to the area of the entire circle

Tags: geometry, circles

I have probably just made some silly mistake but when I calculated the ratio of the area of intersection between two circles of same radius and the centre of the second circle is at the perimeter of the first.

I got the expression $\frac{2}{3}-r\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\pi}$ and am wondering why the ratio is not constant. I feel like it would not be dependent of the radius.

If this incorrect, what is the real ratio? Or if this is correct, why isn't the ratio constant?

Comment: Why do you think it should be constant?

Comment: I really don't know, it is probably my wrong intuition but I think that my doubt comes from the expression I got. Like, what if $r=100$? Is the ratio negative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that the ratio must be independent of the radius of the circle, so your calculation must be incorrect.  However, without seeing your reasoning, I cannot tell you where you made a mistake.

Let $A$ be the center of a circle with radius $r$.  Let $B$ be a point on the circumference of $A$.  Draw a circle with center $B$ passing through $A$.  Then $\odot B$ and $\odot A$ intersect at points $C$, $C'$.  Since $CA = CB = AB = r$, it follows that $\triangle ABC$ is equilateral, and $\angle CAB = 60^\circ$.  Consequently the area of sector $CAB$ is one-sixth of the area of $\odot A$.  But the area of rhombus $ACBC'$ is simply $$|ACBC'| = \frac{1}{2}(AB)(CC') = \frac{1}{2} r \cdot (r \sqrt{3}) = \frac{r^2 \sqrt{3}}{2}.$$  The total area of intersection of the two circles is therefore four times the area of sector $CAB$ minus the area of rhombus $ACBC'$; i.e., it is $$4 \cdot \frac{1}{6} \pi r^2 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} r^2 = \left(\frac{2\pi}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)r^2.$$  Dividing by the area of $\odot A$ gives the ratio $$\frac{2}{3} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\pi} \approx 0.391002,$$ which is independent of $r$ as claimed.